# HTML Video Popping up in IOS Devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, reactjs, safari

I absolutely have no clue why something so simple is giving so much of issues in IOS.

I have a simple Video Element.

```
<video src='/assets/videos/Our-Story.mp4' className='ourstory-video' autoPlay muted playsInline loop>
</video>
```

In some IOS devises this works fine.
But in other (Including some newer models) the video pops up and auto plays in full screen. Which is definitely not something I want to happen.

After researching I added the `playsInline` and the `muted` tags. And kept the tags camel case since it is a React Application.

Simply put, when the page loads I just need the video to play inside container and not pop up in full screen.

Any help pointing me towards the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest You to try those 2 things

First: **add the "controls" attribute**
This will display the default video controls, allowing users to play or pause the video individualy, which might prevent the full-screen autoplay.

And the second thing i reccomend is set the **"webkit-playsinline"** attribute

```
<video
src='/assets/videos/Our-Story.mp4'
className='ourstory-video'
autoPlay
muted
playsinline
loop
controls
webkit-playsinline>
</video>
```

And by the way as I know in react you should use lowercases not Camel cases